# Как работать с массивом в cookie на NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть два запроса: */create /getlist*
В первом запросе я добавляю определенный элемент:

```
dbUtil.create(req.body)
        .then(data=>{
            res.status(200).send(data);
        })
```

Во втором вывожу список. Мне нужно хранить массив в cookiе, при обращении к первому запросу, нужно чтобы элемент добавился в массив. 
Только так нужно делать после каждого вызова к запросу?

```
var items=[]

app.get('/create',(req,res)=>{
  items.push(req.body);
  dbUtil.create(req.body)
        .then(data=>{
            res.cookie('array',items,{ ... })
            res.status(200).send(data);
        })
}
```

Comment: Для начала осознать, что в куках бывают только строки.

Comment: не нужен тут бекенд. перед отправкой запроса на сервер сохрани всё, что тебе нужно, в localstorage